# Powershell [system.reflection.assembly].loadfile() Exception Access is denied when run by Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a very simple Powershell script which I want to use as part of a Jenkins build to return Assembly information. The script contains the following:

```
Write-Host([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile($args[0])).FullName
```

When I try and call this script as part of the Jenkins build I get the following errors:

```
.\GetAssemblyInfo.ps1
Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

At C:\Jenkins\workspace\Tools\NuGetBuildSupport\GetAssemblyInfo.ps1:1    char:50
+ Write-Host([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile <<<< ($args[0])).FullName
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The command runs fine when it is not executing as part of the Jenkins build.

The DLL that is being passed to `loadfile` is not marked as **Blocked**

The execution policy I am using to invoke Powershell is **Bypass**

Comment: What user is the build executor running as? Does it have permission to access the DLL? If you run powershell interactively as that user, are you able to execute the same code?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend navigating to your servers "Services" select the Jenkins service and you can assign a specific user.  As a test try giving Jenkins administrator access and if that works create another user and restrict access.  The fact that it runs fine outside of the Jenkins infrastructure is an indicator for this issue.

- Services: (Search for services in the start menu or the common location: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools)
- Navigate to the Jenkins Service
- Open the properties
- Select the Log in tab and set it to a user with proper permissions (E.g: administrator)